# List all redirects in Nginx

Tags: nginx

I have an Nginx server that has some 50 redirect config files it pulls from.

Is there any way to pull this data as a single list of the server names being listened on once Nginx is running? Or is my best option to manually compile the data?

I have SSH'd in but can't see anywhere obvious that this data could be. Is there a command I could use?

Answer (score 0):

Add in your nginx.conf `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;` or another path where your sites located

after it check your configs 
command `nginx -t`

and reload 
command `service nginx reload`

Comment: `nginx -t` only tests if the config syntax is valid.

Answer (score 0):

If you meant you want to see complete config in one go then you can use below command

```
nginx -T
```

This will tell you if there are any errors in config and if not will print the whole config also

**Edit-1: 5th Jul 2018**

There is nothing like a `apachectl -S` in `nginx`. The only other thing you may try and do is to filter the complete config

```
nginx -T | grep server_name
```

Comment: `nginx -T` only tests if the config syntax is valid and returns that info. I was after a list of the server names it's listening on. I'll update my question to clarify this.